# Pointer issue while running a pointer program

Tags: c

I am a new C language learner. I am currently learning about pointers and got confused while reading this code. At line three, p was defined as a pointer variable, but what exactly happened at line 4? Was a's char array stored in p? Also, at line seven, doesn't i++ mean i = i + i? In this case, why isn't the output 13 instead of 12?
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    int a[]={10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int *p; // Line 3
    p=a; // Line 4
    int i=12; 
    
    printf("%d,%d\n",i++,*p); // Line 7
    printf("%d,%d\n",i++,*(p+1)); 
    printf("%d,%d\n",i++,*(p+2)); 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is JavaScript relevant?

Comment: please include output and expected output (and dont tag unrelated languages please)

Comment: For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)`is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. That means `*p` is the same as `p[0]` which in your case is the same as `a[0]`. And `*(p + 1)` is the same as `p[1]` which in your case is the same as `a[1]`. Etc.

Comment: Also arrays *decays* to pointers to their first element. So the expression `a` is the same as `&a[0]`.

Comment: And for your *second* question (which should be asked as a different question) `i++` and `++i` have different behavior. Any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned the difference.

Comment: I'm confused; line 3 reads `int main()`. Nothing about defining `p`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `p=a`, in most contexts an array *decays* to a pointer to its first element.  This means it's equivalent to `p=&a[0]`.  So while `p` doesn't contain the entire array `a`, it points to the first member of the array, and can be indexed to access subsequent members.

Regarding `i++`, the postfix increment operator evaluates to the *current* value of its operand, and the operand is incremented as a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

The output is:

```
12,10
13,20
14,30
```

When the first `printf()` is called:

- i is 12, printed and then incremented (new value 13).
- p point to array a (first element) so de-referencing the pointer gives 10.

When second `printf()` is called:

- i is 13, printed and then incremented (new value 14).
- p point to array a (first element), you add 1 so it point to the second element in a so de-referencing the pointer gives 20.

When third `printf()` is called:

- i is 14, printed and then incremented (new value 15).
- p point to array a (first element), you add 2 so it point to the third element in a so de-referencing the pointer gives 30.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the array *a* is assigned to the pointer *p* is that the address of *a* (which equals the address of *a*:s first element) is assigned to *p*. Here is a picture which illustrates the situation at line five:

[image: Initialized variables]

The expression *i++* does indeed increment *i* by one but its value is *i* before the increment. That's why the first printed value is 12. Compare this to *++i* which also increments *i* by one but its value is the incremented value of *i*. In general it's a good idea to avoid side effects in expressions; the print statements are better written as

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    printf("%d,%d\n", i + j, *(p + j));
}
```